# Update hash value in the iterator and all of value will be last iteration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to use iterator to update the value in hash, as the hash I created:

```
@period = Date.new(2019,3,1)..Date.new(2019,3,31)

@deals = Deal.includes(:staff).where(shop_id:1, created_at:@period).group_by{|t| t.staff}

data = {}
 staff_id_container = {
  total:{item1: 0, item2: 0, item3: 0}
 }

 Staff.where(shop_id: 1).select(:id).each do |staff|
  staff_id_container[staff.id] = {item1:0, item2:0, item3:0}
 end

 @period.each do |date|
  data[date] = staff_id_container.dup
 end
```

and there are three ways to update the two layer nest structure:

1.replacing the value directly

```
@deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
  deals_by_staff.group_by{|t| t.created_at.to_date}.each do |date, selected_deals|
   data[date][staff.id] = {
    item1: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item1"}.count
    item2: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item2"}.count
    item3: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item3"}.count
   }
  end
 end
```

2.using merge

```
@deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
  deals_by_staff.group_by{|t| t.created_at.to_date}.each do |date, selected_deals|
   data[date][staff.id].merge!({
    item1: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item1"}.count
    item2: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item2"}.count
    item3: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item3"}.count
   })
  end
 end
```

3.using "=" to declare

```
@deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
  deals_by_staff.group_by{|t| t.created_at.to_date}.each do |date, selected_deals|
    data[date][staff.id][:item1] = select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item1"}.count
    data[date][staff.id][:item2] = select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item2"}.count
    data[date][staff.id][:item3] = select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item3"}.count
  end
 end
```

first way works, but if the initial value of `data[date][staff.id]` is `{item1: 0,item2: 0,item3: 0, item4: 0}` and the `item4` will be overwritten.

second and third way are return wrong value, they both let all value of each date become the duplicate of last date.

as I show above:

```
{
 2019-03-01:{
  staff_1:{item1: 0, item2: 3, item3: 1, item4: 5},
  staff_2:{item1: 1, item2: 4, item3: 2, item4: 7},
 },
 2019-03-02:{
  staff_1:{item1: 0, item2: 3, item3: 1, item4: 5},
  staff_2:{item1: 1, item2: 4, item3: 2, item4: 7},
 }
}
```

If I just want to modify one key of `data[date][staff_id]` like `data[date][staff_id][:item1]` or add new key into `data[date][staff_id]`, I need to use 
way second or third.

what is the problem of way second and third?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `dup` with `deep_dup` while building data like

```
data[date] = staff_id_container.deep_dup
```

https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup

Comment: I have tried it function, but it can not solve my problem.
I have another way to beat it and I have made a new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As following first way:

```
@deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
  deals_by_staff.group_by{|t| t.created_at.to_date}.each do |date, selected_deals|
   data[date][staff.id] = {
    item1: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item1"}.count
    item2: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item2"}.count
    item3: select_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item3"}.count
   }
  end
 end
```

If you want to add or change the value in the deep hash, I recommend this way:

```
@deals.each do |staff, deals_by_staff|
  deals_by_staff.group_by{|t| t.created_at.to_date}.each do |date, selected_deals|
   temp = data[date][staff.id].dup
   temp[:item4] = selected_deals.select{|deal| deal.item == "item4"}.count
   data[date][staff.id] = temp
  end
 end
```